# how to detect if a process launched by another application is executing?

Tags: c#, .net, process, desktop-application

I have an application that launches several processes. The purpose of this application is to monitor if they are running once launched and if not, then kill the process if it does not respond or re-launch if it is not running. Running each of the processes that the application knows to launch initially and checking if they are running by the `ObtenerProceso` function (I have the PIDs of each process when they were launched but that does not ensure that the process is dead and another process took the same PID ).

```
public static Process ObtenerProceso(int pid, string ubicacion, string argumentos = "", string dominio = "", string usuario = "")
{
    Process proceso = null;
    Process procesoAux = null;

    if (Process.GetProcesses().Any(x => x.Id == pid))
    {
        procesoAux = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        if (procesoAux.MainModule.FileName.ToUpper() == ubicacion.ToUpper())
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"select * from Win32_Process where ProcessId = {procesoAux.Id}");
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
                if (mo["CommandLine"] != null && mo["CommandLine"].ToString().ToUpper().Replace($"\"{ubicacion.ToUpper()}\"", string.Empty).Trim() == argumentos.ToUpper().Trim())
                {
                    if (dominio.Trim() != string.Empty && usuario.Trim() != string.Empty)
                    {
                        string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
                        int respuesta = Convert.ToInt32(mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
                        if (respuesta == 0 && $"{argList[1]}\\{argList[0]}".ToUpper() == $"{dominio}\\{usuario}".ToUpper())
                            proceso = procesoAux;
                    }
                    else
                        proceso = procesoAux;
                }
        }

    }

    return proceso;
}
```

The function returns `null` in case it does not find the process.

This method has worked well for me, the problem is that it is a little time consuming for the number of processes that I have to monitor. The highest consumptions of time have been in the `select` statement that gets more detailed information about the process as the user who executed the process and the command line that was sent to the executable.

Is there any more effective method for doing this?

Additional clarification

From a single executable the application must launch several instances (but with different initialization arguments), so capturing the process by name is not recommended, in those cases only differentiate them by the command line with which the process was executed. Additionally, I check if the process responds by two criteria, first with the property `Process.Responding` and second every process launched updates from time to time an SQLite database which my application queries to know when was the last report of the process and to know if it is not "locked". I let you the `Aplicacion` class that represents a process that I am going to launch and monitor.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;

namespace Yggdrasil
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an Application to be monitored.
    /// </summary>
    internal class Aplicacion
    {
        #region Definition of private variables.
        private int id;
        private int idMaquina;
        private int pid = -999999999;
        private string nombre;
        private string descripcion;
        private string ubicacion;
        private string argumentos;
        private string dominio;
        private string usuario;
        private SecureString clave;
        private bool activa;
        private DateTime fechaCreacion;
        #endregion

        #region Properties.
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Application ID. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the identification of the process of the Application. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public int PID
        {
            get
            {
                return pid;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the identification of the Machine where the Application is executed. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public int IdMaquina
        {
            get
            {
                return idMaquina;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name of the Application. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public string Nombre
        {
            get
            {
                return nombre;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the description of the Application. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public string Descripcion
        {
            get
            {
                return descripcion;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the location of the Application executable. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public string Ubicacion
        {
            get
            {
                return ubicacion;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the start arguments for the application. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public string Argumentos
        {
            get
            {
                return argumentos;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the Application is active or inactive. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Activa
        {
            get
            {
                return activa;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the user with which the application is executed. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public string Usuario
        {
            get
            {
                return usuario;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the domain in which the application runs. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public string Dominio
        {
            get
            {
                return dominio;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the password of the user with whom the application is running. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public SecureString Clave
        {
            get
            {
                return clave;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the last date the application responded. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime FechaResponde
        {
            get
            {
                return ObtenerUltimoRespondeProceso();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the last date the application reported activity. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime FechaReporte
        {
            get
            {
                return ObtenerUltimoReporteProceso();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the date of creation of the application record. This property can not be set.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime FechaCreacion
        {
            get
            {
                return fechaCreacion;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region implementación de constructores.
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes an object from the Application class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identification of the application.</param>
        public Aplicacion(int id)
        {
            Inicializar(id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes an object from the Application class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identification of the application.</param>
        /// <param name="idMaquina">Identification of the machine where the application is running.</param>
        /// <param name="nombre">Name of the application.</param>
        /// <param name="descripcion">Description of the application.</param>
        /// <param name="ubicacion">Location of the application executable.</param>
        /// <param name="argumentos">Arguments with which the application is executed.</param>
        /// <param name="dominio">User domain of the application.</param>
        /// <param name="usuario">User with which the application is executed.</param>
        /// <param name="clave">Password of the user with which the application is executed.</param>
        /// <param name="activa">Indicates whether the application is active or inactive.</param>
        /// <param name="fechaCreacion">Creation date of the application record.</param>
        public Aplicacion(int id, int idMaquina, string nombre, string descripcion, string ubicacion, string argumentos, string dominio, string usuario, string clave, int pid, bool activa, DateTime fechaCreacion)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.idMaquina = idMaquina;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.descripcion = descripcion;
            this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
            this.argumentos = argumentos;
            this.activa = activa;
            this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
            this.dominio = dominio;
            this.usuario = usuario.ToUpper();
            this.clave = Utilidades.String2SecureString(clave);
            this.pid = pid;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Implementación de métodos privados.
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes an object of the Application class knowing its identification.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identification of the Application.</param>
        private void Inicializar(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                {
                    DataTable dtAplicacion = controladorBD.EjecutarLector($"SELECT * FROM aplicacion WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}");
                    foreach (DataRow drAplicacion in dtAplicacion.Rows)
                    {
                        this.id = id;
                        idMaquina = Convert.ToInt32(drAplicacion["id_maquina"]);
                        nombre = drAplicacion["nombre_aplicacion"].ToString();
                        descripcion = drAplicacion["descripcion"].ToString();
                        ubicacion = drAplicacion["ubicacion"].ToString();
                        argumentos = drAplicacion["argumentos"].ToString();
                        dominio = drAplicacion["dominio"].ToString();
                        usuario = drAplicacion["usuario"].ToString().ToUpper();
                        clave = Utilidades.String2SecureString(drAplicacion["clave"].ToString());
                        if (drAplicacion["activa"].ToString() == "S")
                            activa = true;
                        else
                            activa = false;
                        pid = Convert.ToInt32(drAplicacion["pid"]);
                        fechaCreacion = (DateTime)drAplicacion["fecha_creacion"];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al inicializar un objeto Aplicacion. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the PID of the Application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pid">New process identification for the Application.</param>
        private void ActualizarPID(int pid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                {
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"UPDATE aplicacion SET pid = {pid} WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}");
                    this.pid = pid;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar actualizar el PID. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the date of the last report of the process.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private DateTime ObtenerUltimoReporteProceso()
        {
            DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
            Process proceso = ObtenerProcesoActual();

            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                {
                    int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(controladorBD.EjecutarLector($"SELECT COUNT(*) AS cantidad FROM reporte_proceso WHERE id_proceso = {proceso.Id} AND UPPER(ubicacion) = '{ubicacion.ToUpper()}'").Rows[0]["cantidad"]);
                    if (cantidad > 0)
                    {
                        if (cantidad > 1000)
                            controladorBD.Ejecutar($"DELETE FROM reporte_proceso WHERE id_proceso = {proceso.Id} AND UPPER(ubicacion) = '{ubicacion.ToUpper()}'");

                        fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(controladorBD.EjecutarLector($"SELECT STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', DATETIME(x.fecha)) AS fecha FROM (SELECT MAX(fecha_creacion) AS fecha FROM reporte_proceso WHERE id_proceso = {proceso.Id} AND UPPER(ubicacion) = '{ubicacion.ToUpper()}') x").Rows[0]["fecha"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar obtener la fecha del último reporte de una aplicación. {ex.Message}");
            }

            return fecha;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the date of the last time the application replied.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private DateTime ObtenerUltimoRespondeProceso()
        {
            DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                {
                    object obj_fecha = controladorBD.EjecutarLector($"SELECT STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', DATETIME(fecha_responde)) AS fecha FROM aplicacion WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}").Rows[0]["fecha"];
                    if (obj_fecha != null)
                        fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(obj_fecha), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar obtener la última fecha de respuesta de una aplicación {ex.Message}");
            }

            return fecha;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current application process.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Process ObtenerProcesoActual()
        {
            return Utilidades.ObtenerProceso(pid, ubicacion, argumentos, dominio, usuario);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Implementation of public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Inactiva el proceso.
        /// </summary>
        public void Inactivar()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"UPDATE aplicacion SET activa = 'N' WHERE id_aplicacion = {id} AND activa = 'S'");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar inactivar una aplicación. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Activate the process.
        /// </summary>
        public void Activar()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"UPDATE aplicacion SET activa = 'S' WHERE id_aplicacion = {id} AND activa = 'N'");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar activar una aplicación. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the last date the application responded.
        /// </summary>
        public void ActualizarRespuesta()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"UPDATE aplicacion SET fecha_responde = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar actualizar la fecha de respuesta de una aplicación. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the configuration application.
        /// </summary>
        public void Eliminar()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ControladorSQLite controladorBD = new ControladorSQLite(Controlador.UbicacionBDLocal))
                    controladorBD.Ejecutar($"DELETE FROM aplicacion WHERE id_aplicacion = {id}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error al intentar eliminar una aplicaión. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the application is running.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool EnEjecucion()
        {
            return ObtenerProcesoActual() != null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the application is responding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool EstaRespondiendo()
        {
            return ObtenerProcesoActual().Responding;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Run the application.
        /// </summary>
        public void Ejecutar()
        {
            Process proceso = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = ubicacion,
                    ErrorDialog = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(ubicacion),
                    Arguments = argumentos,
                    Domain = dominio,
                    UserName = usuario,
                    Password = clave
                }
            };

            proceso.Start();
            ActualizarPID(proceso.Id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Kills the current application process.
        /// </summary>
        public void Matar()
        {
            ObtenerProcesoActual().Kill();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Process handles are waitable objects. (See e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx). If your application creates the processes, it can wait for them to terminate just like it is done in the example code on the link I pasted above. No need to query the process list.

Comment: Why don't you go by the process name instead of PID? Process name will be more suitable for this purpose.

Comment: How do you define "running" and "does not respond"? The process exists? Is consuming CPU? Is performing I/O? Updates a database? Responds to activity, e.g. toggling a mutex or sending a message via message queue?

Comment: it depends on what your service is supposed to do. Ex: Your service should respond to a polling message. If it doesn't respond, then it's probably in a bad state. If the message queue hasn't been changed for "X" amount of time, that can be another indicator.

Answer (score 0):

To kill a process by name;

```
    private void TerminateAll()
    {
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("exenamewithoutext"))
        {
            process?.Kill();
        }
    }
```

Here is an idea to refactor your code.

```
public class ProcessRunner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the running process.
    /// </summary>
    private Process RunningProcess { get; set; }    

    /// <summary>
    /// The exepath of the process.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string exePath;

    public ProcessRunner(string exePath)
    {
        this.exePath = exePath;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs the specified executable path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exePath">The executable path.</param>
    public void Run()
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { Arguments = "<Your Args>", FileName = exePath, WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal };
        try
        {
            this.RunningProcess = Process.Start(processInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new ProcessRunnerException(exception.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Terminates this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Terminate()
    {
        if (this.RunningProcess != null)
        {               
            this.RunningProcess.Kill();
            this.RunningProcess.Dispose();
        }
    }
}


public class ProcessManager
{
    private readonly IList<ProcessRunner> MyProcessors{ get; }

    public ProcessManager()
    {
        MyProcessors = new List<ProcessRunner>();
        MyProcessors.Add(new ProcessRunner("myexe.exe")); // Add as many as you want.
    }

    public void RunAll()
    {
        foreach(var proc in MyProcessors)
        {
            proc.Run();
        }
    }

    public void KillAll()
    {
        foreach(var proc in MyProcessors)
        {
            proc.Terminate();
        }
    }   
}
```